# Formal statement of the well-ordering theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Out of interest, how would you write the well-ordering theorem in pure set-theoretic language?

Comment: What? Just $\forall, \exists, \to, \land, \lor, \neg, \in$ and variables? I doubt someone is willing to do that.

Comment: I agree with @Git Gud. This is not an exercise in set theory, this is a horrible exercise in logic, that you give to people who committed serious crimes against society.

Comment: @AsafKaragila OTOH, if you start out with set theory, it can't hurt to convince yourself that these things really *can* be translated, so doing a few relatively easy translations isn't the worst idea one could have...

Comment: @fgp: Of course, I'm not disagreeing with you. This is not one of these easy translations, though.

Comment: I would do this, with statements more complex, because I'm an obsessive, anal weirdo. But not for someone else :p

Answer (score 1):

You can translate the statement

> For every $X$ there is a relation $W \subset X\times X$ on $X$ such that $W$ is a antisymmetric, reflexive, transitive and total, and such that for every $U \subset X$ there's a $x \in U$ with $(x,y) \in W$ for all $y \in U$.

pretty much word-by-word into the first-order language of set theory.

Comment: Only that "relation", "Cartesian product", "ordered pairs", are all *not* in the language of set theory. Also, $U\neq\varnothing$. Oh yeah, $\varnothing$ is also not in the language of set theory.

Comment: @AsafKaragila OK, so word-by-word was exaggerated, but I still maintain that all these concepts are relatively straight-forward to translate. At least compared to something like "Every vector space has a basis" - having to translate *that* would be positively gruesome...

Comment: Oh, I'm not disagreeing.

Comment: I agree with you that "once in my life" it is an exercise worth to be done. The trick is to work "bottom-up". In your example, start with "$W$ is a relation on $X$" and call it $Stat_1$; then "$W$ is antisymmetric" and call it $Stat_2$... and so on, building up all the "catalogue" of the "basic" sentences $Stat_i$ that you need.